# for loop not accepting fed values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a program that simulates fish in a closed system.
I want to be able to create multiple instances of each fish so that each can be tracked individually kind of like pokemon.

I have made this section for my init values:

```
TilapiaWeight = 0.05
TilapiaFCR = 0.1
TilapiaFeedStatus = 10
TilapiaFeedAmount = 0.9*TilapiaWeight
WasteAmt = (1-TilapiaFCR)*TilapiaFeedAmount
Waste = 10
days = ["Mon"],["Tue"],["Wed"],["Thu"],["Fri"],["Sat"],["Sun"]
time = 0
PlantUptakeList = [0.002,0.003] #the uptake rate of each plant
Plants = []#Testing list appending["Green Lettuce","Red Lettuce"]
PlantUptakeSum = 0
PlantsPerM2 = 30
PTX=[]
```

and

my update section
    while TilapiaWeight < 0.5 and Waste >= 0:

```
TilapiaFeedStatus = TilapiaFeedStatus + TilapiaFeedAmount
TilapiaWeight = TilapiaWeight + (TilapiaFCR*TilapiaFeedAmount)
Waste = Waste + WasteAmt
TilapiaFeedStatus=TilapiaFeedStatus - TilapiaFeedAmount
Waste = Waste - PlantUptakeSum
PlantsUpdate = [x+0.0001 for x in PlantUptakeList]
PlantUptakeList = PlantsUpdate
PlantUptakeSum = sum(PlantUptakeList)
PrintTilapia = "Weight",TilapiaWeight,"Waste",Waste,"Day:",time,"Plant uptake",PlantUptakeList
PrintTilapiaList = [TilapiaFeedStatus, TilapiaFeedAmount, TilapiaWeight, Waste, time]
time = time + 1
```

What I can't understand is how I can run this for say Tilapia 1 and Tilapia 2 where they might have different starting weights.
I was also trying to use

```
TilapiaLog.append(set((PrintTilapiaList)))
```

at the end of the second block to log all the values as it iterates but it just makes a longer and longer list of the same set repeated x times...

I then updated according to below suggestions to:

```
class Fish:
def __init__(self, type, number, weight, status, feed, fcr, wastestatus): 
    self.type = type
    self.number = number
    self.weight = weight
    self.status = status
    self.feed = feed
    self.fcr = fcr
    self.wastestatus = wastestatus
def update(self, type, number, weight, status, feed, fcr, wastestatus):
    status = status + feed
    weight = weight + (fcr * feed)
    wastestatus = wastestatus + (1-fcr)
    PrintTilapia = type, number, weight, status, feed, fcr, wastestatus
    print(type, number, weight, status, feed, fcr, wastestatus)

    return type, number, weight, status, feed, fcr, wastestatus
    #...do something to this fish
```

## Then you create many fish instances:

```
tilapia1 = 'Tilapia',1,0.005,1,1,0.15,0
tilapia2 = 'Tilapia',2,0.01,1,1,0.15,0
```

## You group them in a collection

```
fishes = (tilapia1, tilapia2)

print(tilapia1) #('Tilapia', 1, 0.005, 1, 1, 0.15, 0)
```

## then you make them live, evolve, whatever you like

```
time_span = 10
 for t in range(time_span):
  for f in fishes:
    print(f) #('Tilapia', 1, 0.005, 1, 1, 0.15, 0)
    Fish.update(f)
```

## This returns:

```
    Fish.update(tilapia1)
    TypeError: update() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'type', 'number', 'weight', 'status', 'feed', 'fcr', and 'wastestatus'
```

## How can this be if I am giving it these values?

Comment: This sounds like an ideal job for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a class `Tilapia` hold the characteristics and behavior of your fish.

```
class Tilapia:
    def __init__(self, weight, status, ...):
        self weight = weight
        self.status = status
    def update(self):
        ...do something to this fish
```

Then you create many fish instances:

```
tilapia1 = Tilapia(12, 'happy')
tilapia2 = Tilapia(5, 'hungry')
...
```

You group them in a collection

```
tilapias = [tilapia1, tilapia2, ...]
```

then you make them live, evolve, whatever you like

```
for t in range(time_span):
    for tilapia in tilapias:
        tilapia.update()
```

You probably need to find a good tutorial on OOP

Comment: Thank you my dude, I do need a good tut. I was having trouble structuring the iterations, had them running in a while loop, this is exactly what I needed thank you very much.

Comment: Updated question